# UIImagePickerView in Camera mode shows all black on dismissViewController on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an application which uses a UIImagePickerView to allow the user to either take a picture with their camera or select one from the camera roll using the UIImagePickerView.

After getting a picture, I present a different dialog on top of the picker using `[picker presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil]`.

If I run my app as an iPhone app (on my iPad), when I dismiss `myViewController` using `[myviewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` it goes back to either showing the CameraRoll or the CameraFeed to take another picture.

But on the iPad, if I am selecting a picture, it works, but if I am taking a picture using the camera feed, I just get a black screen.

Any idea why?

Comment: when are you showing that extra view controller? after user taps 'Use' button? I tried that and after dismissing extra controller imagePicker was showing chosen picture (yes, ipad), though you cannot do anything else with the image picker at that stage as all the buttons are disabled. are you willing to provide a code sample of your UIPickerDelegate methods?

Comment: After the user taps Use, I get the `-(void)imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info` call on the delegate. In that method I get the image I care about from the `info` and pass that to `myviewcontroller`. I then call `[picker presentViewController:myViewController animated:YES completion:nil;` Then, when I dismiss myViewController by calling `[myviewController.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` it just shows a black screen, and doesn't let me take another picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On iPad when you are using sources different than camera feed, you are presenting UIImagePickerController in a popover and you can use it as long as you wish. But when you decide to pick up the source `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera` the picker window is presenting full screen and you have two cases:

1. If you use your custom controls (showsCameraControls = NO) you can
   take as much pictures as you want with the same controller.
2. If you use default controls (showsCameraControls = YES), after
   taking ONE picture you MUST dissmiss the controller because it is
   unusable again and I guess this is your case. You are putting the
   next controller on the stack after taking the photo, after that you
   are trying to go back to your picker controller but it is unusable
   any more and you can see the black screen.

Apple docs for `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` :

> If you set the image picker’s showsCameraControls property to NO and
>   provide your own custom controls, you can take multiple pictures
>   before dismissing the image picker interface. However, if you set that
>   property to YES, your delegate must dismiss the image picker interface
>   after the user takes one picture or cancels the operation.

If you want to take another picture in this case you have to go back to your base controller and create the UIImagePickerController instance one more.

I hope this will help.

Edit:
The easiest way IMO to rebuild your view controllers stack is to dismiss the picker after taking a photo without animation and after that show the next controller with animation. It will give the user feeling, that the next controller is displayed just after the picker controller without any "flashing".

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        [self presentViewController:<newController> animated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try dismiss normally the UIImagePicker, and when the Pre-viwer View Controller activate viewWillDesapear, you "say" to the previous viewController that when it viewWillAppear, it shows the UIImagePicker again. I think that it works.

Comment: That's what I'm doing currently, basically. I'm showing it in viewDidAppear (I don't think it worked to show it in viewWillAppear). The problem is that when doing that, you see a flash of the previous view controller before the camera view shows again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in an app.  I ended up presenting the image picker for the camera in a popover controller rather than modally for iPad.  I'm not sure if this will work for your app but that's a different approach.  I had no problems doing it this way and liked it much better.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I'll do that. That would at least create some symmetry between the user picking a picture from their camera roll vs. taking a new picture. Not the flow I really wanted, but maybe it will have to do.